# Pandas - How to make a groupment in which a new column is the result of (sum of a column)/(number of itens grouped)?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas, pandasql

I need to make some kind of groupment in which a new column (result) is the sum of the values column divided by number of items found? Could anyone help me, please?

For example:

Table A

```
+-------+------+
| item  | value|
+-------+------+
| x     |  100 |
| y     |  200 |
| y     |  400 | 
+-------+------+
```

Correct Result:

Table B

```
+-------+-----------+
| item  | result    |
+-------+-----------+
| x     | 100/1     |
| y     |(200+400)/2|
+-------+-----------+
```

Code:

```
d = {'item': ['x', 'y', 'y'], 'value': [100,200,400]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Comment: df.groupby(['item']).apply(lambda x: x['value'].sum()/len(x))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
s = df.groupby('item')['value'].agg(lambda x: x.sum()/len(x)) 
print (s)
item
x    100
y    300
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Or divide [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
g = df.groupby('item')['value']
s = g.sum() / g.size()
print (s)
item
x    100.0
y    300.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

But `sum/size` is `mean`, so solution should be simplify by [`GroupBy.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
s = df.groupby('item')['value'].mean()
print (s)
item
x    100
y    300
Name: value, dtype: int64
```